# Regular Expression extract substring (.)*

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to match with the following regex.

```
\d{11}(.*)
```

Which is any 11 digits followed by a string. I want to extract the tailing string whatever it is.

I used RE2::FullMatch but it gives the first half (the 11 digits). How to get the sub-string matched with `(.*)` ?

```
string subStr
RE2::FullMatch("<sip:+19073381121@216.67.108.201:5060;user=phone>;npi=ISDN",(<sip:\+(\d{11}))(.*), &subStr);
```

I am trying to extract everything starting from @ in above string. Basically I want what matches to (.*) but the above function returns `<sip:+19073381121`.

I am not very familiar with regex but I looked at different APIs to extract substrings and found this one usefull

Comment: What language ..? Can you provide an example of what you have tried?

Comment: C++ , also in some case the initial match is more complex which has other special chars like +, : etc

Comment: Try `\d{11}(\w+)`. What you require is the contents of the first group. I'm not sure about your library, but it may represent it with `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: Your regex is fine. Can you provide a compilable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra capturing groups from your regular expression.

```
<sip:\+\d{11}(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sub string matched with (.*) use $1. That is the first capturing group that you specified with the brackets.